# Testing for primes

Tags: python-3.x, primes

I'm trying to write a simple Python (ver 3.5) code for testing a given integer for primality. When I input 97 (for example) I get four `True` outputs.
What am I doing wrong?

```py
# Testing for primality: True or False 25.11.2015
# True means prime, False means divisible

num = int(input('Input an integer for primality test: '))

if num < 2 or num % 2 == 0:
    print('False')
else:
    for i in range(3, int(num ** (1/2)) + 1, 2):
        if num % i == 0:
            print('False')
            break
        else:
            print('True')
```

Comment: Because you have it printed for each `i` which is not dividing the number.

Answer (score 1):

Just unindent the last two lines:

```
# Testing for primality: True or False 25.11.2015
# True means prime, False means divisible

num = int(input('Input an integer for primality test: '))

if num < 2 or num % 2 == 0:
    print('False')
else:
    for i in range(3, int(num ** (1/2)) + 1, 2):
        if num % i == 0:
            print('False')
            break
    else:
        print('True')
```

In Python, `for` can have an `else` clause that only is called when the `for` loop naturally exhausts its iteration.  So if you `break` from a `for` loop it won't print `True`.  It prevents what other languages need a `flag` for that is tested outside the loop as seen in another answer.

You have an additional error, though, in that `2` returns `False`.

Comment: @YehudaKatz, you're welcome!  On SO, you can show thanks by upvoting and selecting an answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can't print `True` in the else statement .Instead you should use a flag and set it to 1 on failing of test and then break the loop

```
flag = False
for i in range(3, int(num ** (1/2)) + 1, 2):
    if num % i == 0:
        flag = True
        break
if flag:
    print('False')
else:
    print('True')
```

Comment: If you defined a function, there would be no need for an extra flag. You could just return `False` as soon as you find a divisor.

Comment: @Jubobs yes there can be tons of ways but this is to provide the OP the reason for multiple printings of `True`